# Invalidate cache at midnight

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Our application uses EclipseLink with default caching configuration - which uses Level 2 cache. A batch job runs on the database at midnight which updates the database values directly. After the batch job runs, the EclipseLink cache has to be invalidated.

[This document](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/cache006.htm#CHEEHFCI) describes the `expiryTimeOfDay` configuration along with `@Cache` annotation. There is also a mention of `<cache>` XML element.

Questions:

- Is there a way to invalidate the entire cache and not for each entity?
- How to use the `<cache>` XML element with example

Comment: You can refer `DatabaseEventListener` & cache documentation - http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cache.htm might help. There is support for Oracle - `OracleChangeNotificationListener`. Else, some schedular could also be fine.

Comment: @NayanWadekar thank you. `@Cache` can be applied to `@MappedSuperClass` which is promising. I could not find any MySQL implementations for `DatabaseEventListener`. Using scheduler is a challenge - invalidate should occur only if the batch job runs successfully (it may not run on all days). And also the `EntityManager` is injected in the DAOs. How do we get the reference of `EntityManager` to invalidate them? (Yes, there are many Entity Managers used)

Comment: But schedular seems a fit here, its not that much difficult - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html Can have some logic to check job status & then invalidate cache. Else can have `expiryTimeOfDay` like 24hrs which should expire after job ends, but it's unconditional & at entity level.

Comment: Do you mean using `evictAll` API? I can have a trigger when the batch job completes and then call `evictAll`. The issue is how to get the reference of `EntityManager`? `EntityManager` is injected into DAO. A new instance of DAO is created for each service --> each DAO gets a new instance of `EntityManager`. `evictAll` should be called on the existing instances of `EntityManager`. So how do we get the reference to the existing `EntityManager`s that are already injected into the alive DAOs/

Comment: No no, you can have dedicated DAO for this task, there you can do `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()`

Comment: Ah, it is on `EntityManagerFactory`. I was thinking it is per entity manager. (If you had put this down as answer, I would have accepted it)

Comment: I think you should post a complete solution, after you get it working. There are various cache levels - 1st/2nd/query etc. unaware of your settings & will be difficult for others to replicate; you can only test this.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Expiration

expiry-time-of-day hour="3"

does that help?